# Regex Custom Redirect in Blogger for every archive.html

Tags: regex, blogger

I need to create a regex Custom Redirect in Blogger. The purpose is to redirect all HTML archives to somewhere else.

Currently I'm using the following in Settings / Search preferences / Custom Redirects:

```
From:/2018_11_21_archive.html
To:/p/somewhere_else.html
Permanent:Yes
```

The problem is that this method requires to add every date, and that's not acceptable.

```
/2016_10_21_archive.html
/2016_10_22_archive.html
/2016_10_23_archive.html
/2017_07_10_archive.html
/2017_07_10_archive.html
/2017_07_10_archive.html
/2018_11_21_archive.html
/2019_11_21_archive.html
...
```

So far I've tried this regex with no success:

```
From:/2018_(.*)
To:/p/somewhere_else.html
Permanent:Yes
```

Comment: Is `somewhere_else.html` a fixed location regardless of the original URL?

Comment: Yes Duniyadnd. «somewhere_else.html» is a page in the very same Blog, not an external URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blogger custom Redirects does not support regex.

But I have a solution for you, use this code, and put it after `<head>`

```xml
<b:if cond='data:view.isArchive and data:view.url contains "_archive"'>
<b:with value='"https://www.example.com/p/somewhere_else.html"' var='destination'>
<script>window.location.replace("<data:destination/>")</script>
<noscript><meta expr:content='"0; URL=" + data:destination' http-equiv='refresh'/></noscript>
</b:with>
</b:if>
```

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Bouh. (Somehow my previous comment was deleted.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the "/" character! Just insert a "\" before.

This line must be like this:

```
From:\/2018_.*
```

But be aware that this way only **/2018_11_21_archive.html** will match.

If you need ALL dates as you mentioned, I recommend this regex below:

```
\/([12]\d{3}_(0[1-9]|1[0-2])_(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))_archive\.html
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Tiego. I tried your proposal `\/2018_.*` and the error message is **«The source and destination values cannot be empty or more than 256 characters and must start with /.»** It seems Blogger has particular rules.

Comment: I see.. So I think the "From" field doesn't accept regular expressions